# Mac Lion - copy and paste leads to files not showing

Tags: mac, macos

When I copy and paste a file from one folder to another in Finder on my Mac (running Lion), I don't see it. This isn't the first time. I've had lion for a while now and it works fine. But for some reason today, when I copy and paste. I go to paste, and the files just don't show up after I paste. Is my Mac hard drive full or something?

Comment: Can you please give us some more details? Is the pasted file lost, or still in its original place? To check your hard drive, launch a Finder window and tick the menu-option View / Show Status Bar. Disk space will be displayed in the status bar.

Comment: also having a similar problem with copying and pasting files, not text. **example:**
buy music online. zip goes to download folder. unzip, and copy folder (with songs) to music folder, using command+c, command+v. only copies the directory, not the files inside. after restart, empty directory is still in music folder. go back to downloads, copy, and paste to music folder. now files inside directory are included in the copy paste.

Comment: *on a side note: my roommate is having a similar issue, although his mac copies the files, then immediately after, the files disappear. although his issue seems to revolve more around Xcode, then just typical copy and pasting.*